# Music Note Player

Tags: software-rec, music

I've started to self-learn music. Is there any software which plays the notes, where I can enter the notes for a composition and it'll play the notes.

What is the best one out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fan of the good old [NoteWorthy Composer](http://www.noteworthysoftware.com/). Compatible with Windows 95 and up!

> NoteWorthy Composer, our notation
>   authoring tool, is a software music
>   composition and notation processor for
>   Windows. It allows you to create,
>   record, edit, print and play back your
>   own musical scores in pure music
>   notation. You can use the built-in
>   transpose feature to quickly adapt a
>   part written for an instrument in a
>   different key to the native key for
>   your instrument. The print feature
>   makes it possible to publish sheet
>   music right from your desktop. You can
>   also save your notation as a MIDI
>   performance for use in other MIDI
>   applications, including software
>   karaoke players.

[image]

The software is shareware, try before you buy. There is a 30-day trial period then the software can be purchased for $49 USD. Well worth it in my opinion. Most musicians you talk to that do recording on their computer probably know about NoteWorthy, it's a classic piece of software which works great to this day.

Answer (score 2):

[Finale Notepad](http://www.finalemusic.com/notepad/) is a $10 basic version of the full Finale suite, which is sort of the gold standard in music notation software.  I used to do professional arranging, and the full Finale was used by me and just about everyone else I ran into.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Linux there is [GNU Denemo](http://www.denemo.org/) which is probably a little less sophisticated than the Windows software above, but it is free. It also can export your finished piece of music to Lilypond.org typesetting software (also free) which will print it out as a professional quality PDF.